# Combined update statement into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following update statement example use for 7 states, what is the best way to combine all in one update statement.

```
update tt
set tax = 'il'
from tax_table tt 
inner join name n on tt.id = n.id
 where states = 'il'
```

---

```
update tt
set tax = 'md'
from tax_table tt 
inner join name n on tt.id = n.id
where states = 'md'
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update tt
set tax = states
from tax_table tt 
inner join name n on tt.id = n.id
where states IN ('tt', 'md')
```

Comment: Each state have a different rate, I need if state = 'il then 'il' if state = 'wa' then 'wa'

Comment: @messi : No, you don't need the if. What you wrote is the same as `if state = 'il' then state if state = 'wa' then state`, which is just the same as `state`. You may as well start using `(if x = 1 then 1) + (if y = 2 then 2) WHERE x=1 and y=2` instead of just doing `1+2`